# viewpager and asynchronous loading

Tags: android-viewpager, android-imageview, android-volley

I've set up a viewpager in my project which scrolls images.  I am feeding the viewpager images from a fragment that is managed by an adapter.  The images are either stored, coming from one of my drawable folders or they come from a url.  I've been using Android's Volley along with a memory cache to acquire the images from the network (url's).  My code to populate the fragment is as follows:

```
// case for no xml url's downloaded
if (url == null) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(getSherlockActivity());
    image.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    layout.addView(image);
} else {

    // use volley NetworkImageView
    NetworkImageView image = new  NetworkImageView(getSherlockActivity());
    image.setImageUrl(url, ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getImageLoader());
    image.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    layout.addView(image);
}
```

I've found that the image scrolling is sluggish in either case and suspect that loading on the main queue is the issue.  Should I be using the "Universal Image Loader" instead of Volley?  I have looked at Android's bitmap fun example, but am concerned about the complexity and it's ability to handle URL's as well as drawables.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem( View pager, final int position )
{

//Some other work related to instantiation of item    

 AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap> mLoadTask = new AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Bitmap>() {              
 //async task for loading images in background

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        pageview[position].setImageBitmap(result);                                         
        //post in ui thread
        //this way you have a reference object for each item(using position)
        //and hence you can start several tasks at the same time             
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Uri... params) {        
        Bitmap bitmap=getBitmap(params[0]);    
        //here getBitmap returns the bitmap using uri arguement
        return bitmap;
    }

};
mLoadTask.execute(Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + image_id));
}
```

This will create a new thread for each `View` hence the main UI thread will run smoothly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You answer assumes that the images are stored in android's contentprovider media store.  In my case, I have url's that are used to pull the images off a server.  Also, there is a potential that the view is already gone when onPostExecute runs as the view pager cycles through views.  I'm guessing that the best way is a memory/disk cache.

Comment: @Jack120 This is just a demonstration of Async Task implementation. I am sure you can make necessary modifications to do it for any purpose you wish. Secondly, the `pageview[position]` ensures that a unique reference is available during `onPostExecute` using the `position` variable. So even if it goes out of scope you don't run into any problem.

Comment: I understand.  But I still need to get the bitmap into memory cache for future loads.

Comment: https://github.com/thest1/LazyList This will take care of all your needs, lazyload, caching on sd card and in memory. It also uses inSampleSize to reduce memory used.